# container-fluid's width is shorter than the body

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The background of my body is in black, and I am trying to make a new layer below it that uses red. So if you scroll down the first block would be black, and then the second block would be red. The problem is, when I set a new container-fluid inside of the HTML, the red block does not fit the full width of the screen, even if I use "width:100%" in my CSS.

The problem seems to be the body, the body is in black and it is wider than the container-fluid div. How can I fix this?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
 body { background-color: black; }
 .newLayer {background-color: red;
            width: 100%;
           }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class ="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <h1>This is the first block in all black.</h1>
     </div>
  </div>

 <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row newLayer">
     <h1>This is supposed to be the second layer.</h1>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `width:100%` from `.newlayer` you will be fine.

**Working code snippet attached below**

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          
<style>
 body { background-color: black; }
 .newLayer {background-color: red;
            
           }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class ="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <h1>This is the first block in all black.</h1>
     </div>
  </div>

 <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row newLayer">
     <h1>This is supposed to be the second layer.</h1>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
  </html>
```

You can copy this file in your local file and then link it inside the head tag.

[HERE IS THE LINK TO THE FILE](http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js)

Or just use `<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` in the head tag as I have used. In that case remove your local file.

Comment: You are using the css from their site, I have it local. Do you know how I can still use sass using this link:  href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
?